# Parsing a JSON URL

Tags: java, web

I'm trying to figure out why I can not load the characters from a web-page, and am confused.

When I try to do one website, such as jakarta.apache.org; I can echo the output fine.. When I try an NBA website I'm trying to parse; it just spins..

Any idea what I can do?

```
//http://stats.nba.com/stats/commonplayerinfo?PlayerID=201566

           String works= "http://jakarta.apache.org";
           String doesntwork=   "http://stats.nba.com/stats/commonplayerinfo?PlayerID=201566";
           InputStream in = new URL(eitherOne).openStream();

 try {
System.out.println( IOUtils.toString( in ) );
} 
finally {
IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
}
```

I tried logging the URL, and when I copy and paste it; it loads fine in the browser. So not sure what else could explain why it works on one address and not the other.

Comment: Even http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://stats.nba.com/stats/commonplayerinfo?PlayerID=203507 doesn't seem to work.. Must be an issue with NBA.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out stats.nba.com restrits some users.. To get around this; I changed the user agent to mimic a browser, i.e:

```
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Mobile Safari/537.36");
```